# Is there any way to convert this to train the convolutional autoencoder?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have this issue when trying to create a convolutional autoencoder.

```
________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_56 (InputLayer)        (None, 8192, 4)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_147 (Conv1D)          (None, 8192, 64)          8256      
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_138 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 8192, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_82 (MaxPooling (None, 256, 64)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_148 (Conv1D)          (None, 256, 32)           32800     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_139 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 256, 32)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_83 (MaxPooling (None, 16, 32)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_149 (Conv1D)          (None, 16, 32)            16416     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_140 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 16, 32)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling1d_48 (UpSampling (None, 256, 32)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_150 (Conv1D)          (None, 256, 64)           65600     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_141 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 256, 64)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling1d_49 (UpSampling (None, 8192, 64)          0         
=================================================================
Total params: 123,072
Trainable params: 123,072
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I need to convert up_sampling1d_49 `[(None, 8192, 64)]` to the same shape of input_56 `[(None, 8192, 4)]` to train the autoencoder. Is there any way to do this?

I've tried to use Flatten layer with a MLP layer.

```python
import keras as K
import scipy as sp

##Creating the model
fil,col=8192,4
entrada = K.layers.Input(shape=(fil,col) )

c1 = K.layers.Conv1D(filters=64,kernel_size= 32, padding='same')(entrada)
lr1 = K.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.35)(c1)
p1 = K.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=32)(lr1)

c2 = K.layers.Conv1D(filters=32,kernel_size=16, padding='same')(p1)
lr2 = K.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.25)(c2)
p2 = K.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=16)(lr2)

c3 = K.layers.Conv1D(filters=32,kernel_size=16, padding='same')(p2)
lr3 = K.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.25)(c3)
p3 = K.layers.UpSampling1D(size=16)(lr3)

c4 = K.layers.Conv1D(filters=64,kernel_size=32, padding='same')(p3)
lr3 = K.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.35)(c4)
p4 = K.layers.UpSampling1D(size=32)(lr3)

model = K.models.Model(entrada,p4)
```

Answer (score 0):

The input to the UpSampling1D layer has shape `(batch, steps, features)` and output has shape `(batch, upsampled_steps, features)`. Therefore, the UpSampling1D layer won't change the channel dimension. So the choice you have is to convert the filters number of `conv1d_150`.

```py
c4 = K.layers.Conv1D(filters=64,kernel_size=32, padding='same')(p3)
lr3 = K.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.35)(c4)
p4 = K.layers.UpSampling1D(size=32)(lr3)
```

This will change the output shape of `conv1d_150` and `leaky_re_lu_141` to `(None, 256, 4)`, and  `up_sampling1d_49` to `(None, 8192, 4)`.